# Call Identity Server protected resources from another web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I'm working on an application which has Angular in the frontend, a few services in the backend and IS4 as a token provider. I keep all user data (email, passwords, avatar etc.) in the `AspNetUsers` table to which only IS4 has access.

In one of the web services, I implemented logic which requires to get a list of users who meet some business requirements. To do that I added the `UserController` to IS4 web service and exposed an endpoint that returns that list.

Problem is that when I decorate the controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute, I can't reach that endpoint and I get a 404 error and request URI is changed in the response to

```
https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FUser%2FSearch%3Fcategory%3Dpremium%26area%3Dsap
```

When I remove the attribute, it works properly. I want to keep that attribute of course.

**My question is**: what do I need to do to make a successful call from web service to IS4 to get that user's list? Set authorization headers? I did that. Configure clients in IS4? I tried that but most likely I did that incorrectly. Is my design bad? Then how should it look like?

This is the code I have

Web service:

```
//_discoverySettings.IdentityUrl = https://localhost:5001
var url = $"{_discoverySettings.IdentityUrl}/User/Search?category={category}&area={area}";

var idpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("IDPClient");
var accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
idpClient.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
var content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
requestMessage.Content = content;
var response = await idpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

IS4 `UserController`:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IdentityContext _identityContext;
    .
    .
    .

    [HttpGet("search")]
    public Task<List<UserDto>> Search(string category, string area)
    {
        return _identityContext.Users
                               .Where(x => x.Category == category && x.Area == area)
                               .Select(x => new UserDto{ ... })
                               .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

If needed I can provide more code, configuration etc.

IS4 works on my nerve sometimes so please be as verbose as possible.

**[EDIT]**

I have followed MD Zand answer and I added missing configuration to IS. 'challenger' is backend service and 'challenger_web' is angular frontend. I added **LocalApi.ScopeName** scope to both back and front. Decorated the controller with `[Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)]`
And added this part `services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();` in IS startup. I also added this to AddIdentityServer() method options

```
options.Discovery.CustomEntries.Add("challenger", "localhost:5002");
options.Discovery.CustomEntries.Add("challenger_web", "localhost:4002");
```

This time I got 401 - Unathorizaed with the followieng message in the IS console

```
[08:58:02 Error] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator
Checking for expected scope IdentityServerApi failed
{
  //some info
}
[08:58:02 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.LocalApiAuthentication.LocalApiAuthenticationHandler
IdentityServerAccessToken was not authenticated. Failure message: insufficient_scope
```

I saw that the **IdentityServerApi** scope was added in the database. But when I deserialized the JWT this is what I saw

```
//rest omitted
"aud": [
  "challenger",
  "https://localhost:5001/resources"
],
"client_id": "challenger_web",
"idp": "local",
"scope": [
  "openid",
  "profile",
  "challenger"
],
```

IdentityServerApi scope should be included in the scope array. So what I did is I added that to the scope array in the UserManagerSettings in angular project

```
scope: "openid profile challenger IdentityServerApi",
```

Hope that helps other people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you need add this line to the identity server to have some endpoints in your IdentityServer settings:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalApiAuthentication( );
```

Also you may need some more configurations. Check [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/apis/add_apis/) for more details;

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me :). I also had to add the scope to the frontend settings. See my [Edit] section in the question